# How to tunnel to into the private network of my docker containers on Bluemix?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, tunnel, private-network

I have some docker containers running on `Bluemix` using private IP addresses. I would now like to setup a tunnel from my laptop (running linux) to access the private network on `Bluemix`.

I had first created a container running an ssh-server. Using `ssh -D` I was able to setup a `SOCKS5` proxy connection. This worked fine with Chrome but not all applications support a SOCKS proxy.

```
(google-chrome --proxy-server=socks5://localhost:<tunnel port>)
```

So I tried to create a container with an `OpenVPN` server. Unfortunately this does not work on `Bluemix` as the containers are not running privileged and thus can not create a tun device.

`Bluemix` also has a VPN and a Secure Gateway service, which sound promising but so far I could not figure out how to get those working.

Does anybody know if it is possible to make the private docker network available locally and how to connect to that?

Comment: Here's info to get you started on the VPN service: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/vpn/index.html
<br><br>
Here's info to get you started on the Secure Gateway service:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking containers should be used to implement services available to external applications (an APIs service, or a runtime, or a dbms, or something like that).

According to this, what you could achieve is a set of services available for you on different containers, and a single container working as SSH tunnel gateway, making your local environment connected to it using SSH and defining a set of local and remote SSH ports forwarding, with different policies according to the service/port and the IP of the service.

It should work for all the services, and you haven't to use a socks proxy to forward requests to different hosts: using remote SSH forwarding your SSH endpoint will redirect your requests to the right service inside the local/private lan.
I found that this guide describes correctly how to work with local&remote port forwarding.

http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html

About the OpenVPN solution, as you already know it is not possible to use software requiring privileged mode on containers, because it couldn't be allowed on Bluemix due to security reasons: if you wish to have this kind of solution I strongly suggest you to use OpenVPN on a VM on Bluemix UK region (still beta but an architecture expected to be the final architecture as soon as VM service will become GA service)

I think that these options are the ones available on Bluemix to achieve what you describe without using the VPN service suggested by @bill-wentworth

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like my development use case is not really supported then. I'm trying the VM approach in UK region but it looks like it is also not that easy as the private IP of the VM can not reach the private IP of the containers.
The VPN service seems to require an IPSec gateway that is reachable from the internet, which I don't have. So using that directly does not seem to be possible. But as my VM also has a public IP it might be possible to set up an IPSec gateway on the VM and then use OpenVPN to make that available. Just quite complicated for such a simple use case ;-)

Comment: The containers network and the VM one are distinct due to infrastructure reasons. So you still have to set a container with a public IP and connect it to the OpenVpn VM. Three different and distinct private networks connected through a VPN on a VM, a little bit complicated :-)